# Insert to SQL Server database from jquery mobile application using a server side script (coldfusion)

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

I've built a jQuery mobile app that gets its content from an external SQL server database via JSON and a server side script (ColdFusion CFC) that interfaces with the database. This app has been packaged as a native app using PhoneGap. I need to enable the jQuery mobile app to be able to write back to the external SQL server db.

Im new to mobile development but have several years of server side development using ColdFusion. I am guessing that the best way to do this is for the mobile app to send the results of the submitted form elements to a server side script for processing. I dont want the native app to send this "as a web page" but rather stay in the app to do it (via AJax I assume).

My server side script will be written in ColdFusion and handles input sanitation and database interaction...I just need to figure out what is the best way to submit from my jQuery app to the server side script, but do it while staying inside of my native application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty much doing the same thing. Server side `Coldfuison8/MySQL`, front end `Jquery Mobile` (, `requireJS`) with all forms submits routed through AJAX to avoid reloading a page.

I'm using a generic form submitter in my `controller.js`, which looks like this:

```
var ajaxFormSubmit = 
     function ( form, service, formdata, targetUrl, successHandler, dataHandler, errorHandler ){
     $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "post",
        url: service,
        data: formdata,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function( objResponse ){
            if (objResponse.SUCCESS == true ){
                // alert("success!");
                // this passes the response object to the success handler 
                // in case data needs to be ... handled.
                dataHandler == "yes" ? successHandler( objResponse ) : successHandler();
            } else {
                // alert("AJAX failed!");
                if ( errorHandler != "" ){
                    errorHandler();
                    }
                }
            },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            //alert("something else failed");
            showErrors( [["server-request-error", "server_error"]], XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown );
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm returning results as a response object, which will contain `Success = True/false`, `data` (if there is any) and `Error = error message`.

A function call will look like this:

```
// the form 
var form = $(this).closest('form'),
    // trigger for cfcase inside my cfc
    switcher = form.find('input[name="form_submitted"]').val(),
    // which cfc to call
    service = "../cfcs/form_handler_abc.cfc",
    // the method in your cfc you are calling (validation/commit to database)
    method = "process",
    returnformat = "JSON",
    // not using 
    targetUrl = "",
    // serialized form plus any value you need to pass along
    formdata = form.serialize()+"&method="+method+"&returnformat="+returnformat,
    // specific error routine to run
    errorHandler = function(){
        // in my case, reset the whole form
        cleanUp( $('form:jqmData(search="regular")'), "results" )   
        },
    // inside my success handler I'm switching depending on submitted form
    // `response` will be the AJAX object.response = whatever you send back from the server
    successHandler = function( response )  {
        switch (switcher) {

            // form A - this is for a search form handling the results
            case "getProducts":
                // clean up
                $('.ajaxContainer, .pagination').addClass('fade out').remove();
                // AJAX data received
                var makeUp = response.DATA;
                // don't forget to trigger create to enhance all JQM elements you are sending
                $('.results').append( makeUp ).trigger('create');
                // redraw - will fire JQM updatelayout
                $(window).trigger('dimensionchange');
                // will set bindings on new elements
                bindResults( $('.results').closest('div:jqmData(role="page")') );
                break;

            case "A": 
                // do sth else
                break;

            case "B": 
                // do sth else
                break;          
                }
            };
        // now pass all of the above to the ajaxFormsubmit
        ajaxFormSubmit( form, service, formdata, targetUrl, successHandler, handleData, errorHandler);
```

I have a number of CFCs, each with a main `cfswitch` and `cfcase` for each submitted form. I have built my backend using [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1557-Object-Oriented-Form-Helpers-And-Reusing-Form-Validation-On-The-Client.htm) sample. Took a while to get going, but now it's running more or less smooth.

Let me know if you have some questions regarding the above.